# I want to copy all highlighted and shaded text from Word file to Excel along with the colors through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to copy all Highlighted and Shaded text from Word file to Excel with same color in Word file through VBA.

I was able to copy only highlighted text from word to word. But the actual task is to copy all highlighted and shaded text to Excel and sort all the data according to color in Excel.

I use this code and it works fine to just copy from word to word but there is no formatting this code copies only text no colors;

```
Sub ExtractHighlightedText()

    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim s As String
    With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = ""
            .Highlight = True
            Do While .Execute
                s = s & Selection.Text & vbCrLf
            Loop
        End With
    End With
Set oDoc = Documents.Add 
oDoc.Range.InsertAfter s 

End Sub
```

Code for converting from Shaded to Highlighted:

```
Sub ConvertTextsFromShadedToHighlighted()

    Dim objParagraph As Paragraph
    Dim objCharacterRange As Range

    For Each objParagraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  If objParagraph.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then
  If objParagraph.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor <> wdColorAutomatic 
Then
      objParagraph.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
      objParagraph.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
     End If
   End If
 Next objParagraph

 For Each objCharacterRange In ActiveDocument.Characters
    if objCharacterRange.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor <> 
 wdColorAutomatic Then
  objCharacterRange.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
  objCharacterRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
 End If
 Next objCharacterRange
End Sub
```

Comment: Technically you're not *copying* anything; you're *transcribing* string content. You'll need to get the clipboard involved if you want to formatting to come along (note, color themes may be different between the two), and to work with Excel you'll need to create a new instance of `Excel.Application`.

Answer (score 1):

May try something like this

Edit: Tried to include Extraction of Shaded text (Any color) along with  Highlighted text by using tow finds. Following workaround methods are adopted

1. For finding Shaded text (of any color) find is executed for `.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic` and the range excluding that selection was picked up as shaded text and color. Method somehow crudely performing when selection contain pure text characters but still picking up wrong color value when selection contain non text characters (i.e. paragraph marks etc). Otherwise it is working up to expectation. Otherwise there is always another option open to iterate through all the characters in the documents. But that option was left out as it is very slow and impractical for large documents.
2. As no simple method (or property) found by me to convert `HighlightColorIndex` to RGB color value, The same was applied to one character's `Font.ColorIndex` and later extracted as `Font.Color`

So finally the solution become messy and somehow crude, I am not at all satisfied with and *more answers are invited from experts for simple direct solutions in these regards*.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExtractHighShadeText()
Dim Exc As Excel.Application
Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim s As String, Rw As Long
Set Exc = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Exc.Visible = True
Set Wb = Exc.Workbooks.Add
Set Ws = Wb.Sheets(1)
Rw = 0

Dim Rng As Range, StartChr As Long, EndChr As Long, OldColor As Long, Clr As Long
''''''''''''''''''''HiLight''''''''''''''''''
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Characters(1)
OldColor = Rng.Font.Color
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = ""
            .Highlight = True
            Do While .Execute

            'These two line Converting HighlightColorIndex to RGB Color
            Rng.Font.ColorIndex = Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex
            Clr = Rng.Font.Color

            Rw = Rw + 1
            Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = Selection.Text
            'Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex
            Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Interior.Color = Clr
            'For sorting on HighlightColorIndex
            'Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value = Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex
            'For sorting on HighlightColorIndex RGB value
            Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value = Clr
            Loop
        End With
Rng.Font.Color = OldColor
'''End Hilight''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'WorkAround used for converting highlightColorIndex to Color RGB value
StartChr = 1
EndChr = 0
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Characters(1)

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = ""
            '.Highlight = True
            .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic

            Do While .Execute
              EndChr = Selection.Start
              Debug.Print Selection.Start, Selection.End, StartChr, EndChr, IIf(EndChr > StartChr, "-OK", "")

              If EndChr > StartChr Then
              Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=StartChr, End:=EndChr)
              Clr = Rng.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
              Rw = Rw + 1
              Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = Rng.Text
              Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Interior.Color = Clr
              Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value = Clr
              End If
              StartChr = Selection.End
            Loop

              If EndChr > StartChr Then
              Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=StartChr, End:=EndChr)
              Clr = Rng.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
              Rw = Rw + 1
              Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = Rng.Text
              Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Interior.Color = Clr
              Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value = Clr
              End If

        End With


    If Rw > 1 Then
    Ws.Range("A1:B" & Rw).Sort Key1:=Ws.Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    Ws.Range("B1:B" & Rw).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing.. Just two more things, First, here you are successfully copying highlighted texts but not the shaded text, Second, can we keep the colors of text from Word to excel. If these two things can be done than YOU ARE THE BEST!!!

Comment: Edited code for Sorting On RGB value of Highlight color and changing excel cells interior color to that of highlight color

Comment: Nice work sir, but the word file is having some highlighted text and some shaded text. The code is copying all highlighted text along with color that is excellent. But can we get shaded text along with color as well..

Comment: AFAIK finding Shading and highlights in a single search may not be possible. Also finding any shading is difficult for me. What I could say is to use   `Find.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow` type statement  to find Shading of Yellow only at a time.  may experts would come with some solution to this.  Looping to find different colors of shading looks impractical to me.

Comment: Answer edited for adding extraction of Shaded text. Please feedback.

Comment: Lets give a last try, I found one code which converts all shaded texts to highlighted. But the problem with that is, it will convert with one colour only like in this example its Pink. If you find a way to change each shaded para's colour differently then the task is done. It doesn't matter what colour is it, for example shaded para is of colour Red but when we convert it to Highlighted it turn to Green I am ok with it. But all Red shaded paras should Green in that case. Here is the code;